# How do i provide higher precedence to OR than AND in mysql query where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, operators, operator-precedence

I want to have a query of the following nature :

```
"SELECT * FROM table1 where column1=1 OR column2=1 OR column3=1 AND column4=1 OR column5=1";
```

According to the operator precedence, AND operation will be performed first and then the OR operations. But in my case I want that 
column1=1 OR column2=1 OR column3=1  --> this and
column4=1 OR column5=1  --> this are performed first and the results from these bound by AND operation for the final result.

Can I just add brackets to get higher precedence for OR like in most programming languages or how is this done ?

Comment: Where did you end up after searching for `mysql operator precedence`? I end up [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html): "To override this order and group terms explicitly, use parentheses"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets and wrap each part, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
where (column1=1 OR column2=1 OR column3=1) AND (column4=1 OR column5=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add parentheses.  In addition, you could express the logic using `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE 1 IN (column1, column2, column3) AND 1 IN (column4, column5);
```

Comment: I too was about to correct the OP to 'parentheses' then I remembered [BODMAS](http://www.skillsyouneed.com/num/bodmas.html)!

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . We Americans call them "parentheses", but we understand those other dialects ;)  Wikipedia has an extensive discussion on the subject:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket.  I tend to think of "bracket" as a superset of parentheses.

Comment: Apparently the US equivalent of BODMAS is PEDMAS (Parentheses, Exponents, Division and Multiplication, Addition and Subtraction). We UK software engineers would tend to call them parens too, I think.